# java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.net.Uri.getScheme()'

Tags: java, android, image, upload, server

I am Trying To upload image to server from gallery and camera.When i Choose image from gallery to upload to server its Work Perfactly.But when i Select camera captured Image for upload to server Its Crash And Showing the error.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.net.Uri.getScheme()' on a null object reference
```

At OnActivityResult.

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE && resultCode == RESULT_OK
                && null != data) {
            Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
            String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };

            Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,
                    filePathColumn, null, null, null);
            cursor.moveToFirst();

            int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
            String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
            cursor.close();

            decodeFile(picturePath);
            new ImageUploadTask().execute();
        }else {

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "User Canceled",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
```

i got the error on this line in onActivityResult

```
 Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,
                        filePathColumn, null, null, null);
                cursor.moveToFirst();
```

The method i used for open camera on button click.

```
  loadimage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {


                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Add_Info.this);
                builder.setMessage("Select Image From")
                        .setCancelable(true)
                        .setPositiveButton("Camera", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

                                Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                                startActivityForResult(intent, CAMERA_REQUEST);
                                mImageCaptureUri = Uri.fromFile(new File(Environment
                                        .getExternalStorageDirectory(), "tmp_avatar_"
                                        + String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis())
                                        + ".jpg"));
                            }
                        })
                        .setNegativeButton("Gallery", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                Intent i = new Intent(
                                        Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                                        android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);

                                startActivityForResult(i, RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE);

                            }
                        });
                AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
                alert.show();


            }
        });
```

Help Me solve this problem.I don't know How t get this error even after i used is already in my Previous PROJECT.

THANKS in Advance

Comment: data.getData(); is returning null

Comment: you should post the code of `PICK_IMAGE` not `CAMERA_REQUEST`

Comment: Please post the entire stack trace, and indicate what lines in the stack trace correspond to lines in your code snippets.

Comment: i did't get you @QAMAR

Comment: try debugging your code, data.getData() or data will be null

Comment: i update my Quastion @DerekFung #CommonsWare

Comment: did you get any solution for this issue?

Comment: @RushDroid did you get any solution for this issue?

Comment: @RaviMakvana did you get any solution for this issue?

Comment: @Javacoder for Upload image or pick image ?

Comment: @RushDroid pick image...

Comment: i suggest you to use EasyImage Library for pick image from gallery @Javacoder link https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/2725

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had same issue when working with Camera api and Intent of onActivityResult, finally I found out it depends on your android device version, in Android M (Marshmallow - 6.0–6.0.1 ) onActivityResult intent is like below :

```
requestCode : 230 resultCode : -1 intent :Intent{dat=file:///storage/emulated/0/Pictures/Rahnama/IMG_20160508_121332_1519065    564.jpg typ=image/jpeg } RESULT_OK : -1
```

and for android versions lower than Marshmallow:

```
requestCode : 230 resultCode : -1 intent : Intent { dat=content://media/external/images/media/309 (has extras) } RESULT_OK : -1
```

I think you must check android version onActivityResult and the for android versions Marshmallow to get direct file from path in the Uri and Intent:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT == Build.VERSION_CODES.M){
            final Uri data = intent.getData();
            final File file = new File(data.getPath());
            // now you can upload your image file
    }else{
           // in android version lower than M your method must work
    }
```

I hope it can be useful for you.

Comment: Can you please explore this answer deeply??

Answer (score 0):

I meet this problem either, after many test, I found its because I set the attribute named `android:windowIsTranslucent=true`, if I delete this attribute from style, it always work.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (null != account.getPhotoUrl()) {
    // Write code here
}
```